# Can we do something like performBlockAndWait: without managed object context

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.5

Say I am in a background thread. Say I want to execute something on the main thread and wait till it's finished.

How would I do so?

I suppose I can do

```
   [[NSOperationQueue new] addOperationWithBlock:^{
        [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]addOperationWithBlock:^{
            //Do something on main queue
            [[NSOperationQueue new] addOperationWithBlock:^{
                //Do something after finish
            }];
        }];
    }];
```

I want to do someothing like

```
//do stuff
[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]addOperationWithBlockAndWaitTillFinished:^{
        //Do something on main queue

 }];
 //Do something after finish
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I think you are looking for is `dispatch_sync` It's like `dispatch_async` but the block is performed synchronously,

Just be sure not to run the block on the same queue as the current queue, or you'll deadlock.

Comment: perfect. I hate those gbp directly though. Still that's the way to go.